# Adobe Scout does not start

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, adobe-scout

I´m compiling through Flashedevelop with Flex 4.6.0 for Flash Player 14.0.
Scout is ready and is also detecting other swfs.
But when i start my swf, absolutely nothing happens.
I´m not talking about Advanced Telemetry, Scout does not even detect the swf at all.
What could be wrong?

Comment: Maybe your SWF crashes right at the start? Does it ever work if run in FD's debugger flash player?

Comment: Is telemetry for your SWF enabled at all?  I am using FlashBuilder 4.6 which doesn't set telemetry, but there's a utility SWFScountEnabler that will enable telemetry for any SWF.

Comment: Hi, i managed to make it work. It only works in the browser? Not in the standalone player? Didn´t read about that anywhere. Or is it just like this on my pc?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself. 
You must launch the SWF in a web browser with flash installed. You can also install the debugger version of flash to get extra info about memory allocation.

I was never able to activate the profiler by running the SWF from the Flash IDE.